Facing issue with asciidoctor.jvm.convert 2.4.0 and spring docs 2.0.5 release Which is unable to load the child.html in the index html
test {
useJUnitPlatform()
outputs.dir snippetsDir
}

asciidoctor {
configurations "asciidoctorExtensions"
inputs.dir snippetsDir
dependsOn test

doLast {

copy{

from ("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5")

into "$buildDir/resources/main/public/docs")

include "**/*.html"

}

Here is the example i refered the above solution from-

 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs-samples/blob/main/restful-notes-spring-hateoas/build.gradle

I am getting below error when i try to load index HTML
Unresolved directive in index.adoc - include::child.adoc[]
I tried below solution -
THe below solution didn't worked
asciidoctor {    
 configurations 'asciidoctorExtensions'     
inputs.dir snippetsDir    
 sources {         
include 'index.adoc'   
  }    
 
dependsOn test
 }   


github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin/issues/549 . Adding asciidoctor.baseDirFollowsSourceDir() in the asciidoctor task fix the issue.The asciidoctor.jvm.convert version should be greater than 3.3.1
